# freebsd syslog server limit

Tags: freebsd, syslog, maximum

whats the max numbers of syslog servers can I configure on a freebsd machine?

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking how many computers you can have forwarding their syslog data to a freebsd machine?  Or do you actually mean you want multiple syslog daemons running on that server, for some very unusual reason?

In either case the answer is probably 'it depends'.  How much syslog entries would be added per minute, day, other.  How fast are your drives, how much network capacity do you have.  What syslog deamon are you actually using?  Do you have large enough drives to handle all the messages you want to log?

Without more details, that you may not have, the answer is probably going to be, try it and find out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if there is a limit to the number of servers you can list in `/etc/syslog.conf` using `@server`?

I took a look at the sysklogd source code which was taken from BSD sources. It may have diverged but the basic implementation is probably the same.

Each non-comment, non-blank line, including `@server`, is converted into a structure and added to a linked list.

Thus, theoretically, the answer is "no, there is no limit." Practically, you are limited by CPU, memory, disk, network, etc., resource limits.